# Altering font in a programmatic navigation bar (Objc)(Xcode 7.3)

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, xcode7.3

How can you alter the font on a programmatic Navigation bar(title)? I've searched for quite a while and have seen a good variety of code - yet none that works in my project.

The following is some of the things I've tried:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                            UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor     greenColor],
                      UITextAttributeTextShadowColor: [UIColor     redColor],
                     UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset: [NSValue     valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)],
                                 UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont     fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0f]
 }];
```

---

```
`NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 0.0;
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 2.0);
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{
                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor],
                            NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont     fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:0.0f],
                          NSShadowAttributeName : shadow
```

}];

---

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: 
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
    [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, 
       [UIFont fontWithName:@"LeagueGothic-Regular" size:16.0], NSFontAttributeName,nil]];
```

Some background info: the navigationController is set programmatically and holds 4 views in a stack. Any hints/help with this seemingly simple problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: @rmaddy: thank you for the suggestion (taken and I definitely should have done that from the beginning!).

Comment: Using `UINavigationBar appearance` affects all instances of `UINavigationBar` that are created after you call `UINavigationBar appearance`. So make sure you are calling that before the nav bar is created. If you wish to only affect a single nav bar, don't use `UINavigationBar appearance`. Instead, call `setTitleTextAttributes` on the specific nav bar instance.

Comment: Before the NavBar is created I have `NSDictionary *textAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor colorWithRed: 44.0/255 green:69.0/255 blue:86.0/255 alpha: 0.90f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Machinato- Light"    size: 22], NSFontAttributeName, nil];`  Then 
`[[UINavigationBar appearance]setTitleTextAttributes: textAttributes];` -no success.

Comment: Right, but is this before or after the nav bar is being created? That code will only work if it is called before the nav bar is created.

Comment: Yes, the attributes code is being called before the nav bar is created. I checked again with a breakpoint just now.

Comment: What do you mean by "before the nav bar is created"? If this is a navigation controller, you do not create any nav bar. The navigation controller creates it for you. It sounds like your appearance code is running _after_ the navigation controller does that. In that case, your problem is about how to use the appearance proxy or how to use a navigation controller — it would have nothing to do with nav bar title font at all.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `titleTextAttributes`. There is nothing "deprecated" about it. Treat it like an NSAttributedString's attributes and it will work just fine.

Example:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name:"Chalkduster", size:20)!,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black
    ]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding ^_^ I've been using `titleTextAttributes`(I've updated my question). Please let me know if there is anything else you believe I'm missing.

Comment: Well, the first one is clearly wrong. The whole UITextAttributeFont thing is out the window. That's why I said "treat it like an NSAttributedString's attributes". My answer is right; I don't know enough about what you're doing to know why you think it isn't.

Comment: Added actual code and screen shot of actual result. Go ye and do likewise.

Comment: Thanks for the example code- it's always good to compare and make sure I wasn't missing anything during this attempt in my code.

Comment: I agree. Your first move should always be to make a clean new project and try whatever is giving you trouble, to convince yourself that it normally works. Then you can try to track down what you are doing in your _real_ project that _prevents_ it from working. If this isn't working for you, _you_ are doing something else wrong — but I can't see from here what it is, as you have given insufficient information.

Answer (score 0):

From the guidance of SO users who commented and answered (thank you @rmaddy and @matt) I found a workaround. I altered the font (as well as color and size)attributes in ViewDidLoad of each view controller(VC) individually like so:

`[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName: @"FONT NAME" size: 20.f], NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor]}];`

Additionally, I had to set the nav bar title in ViewDidAppear for the rootVC- when the app opens initially, the title is fine in ViewDidLoad but when I navigated to the rootVC from another VC the title disappeared.

I included this last part in case it can help someone else in the future.